# GO : ssh into Unix get users /etc/passwd and finding groups associated for every user

Tags: arrays, go, unix

I am new to Golang. I am able to get the list of users from cat /etc/passwd. What I am trying to achieve is that for every user returned by cat /etc/passwd, I want to run the "id -user" command and map the user groups to that user. What data structure should I use? OR

Is there a Shell command that I can get fire to achieve the above?
I tried this -

for user in $(awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd); do groups $user; done

AND

tail -n +1 -F /etc/passwd | head -n +2500 -f":" /etc/passwd

Answer (score 1):

> What data structure should I use?

You could use anything from arrays, lists, maps, dictionaries, to anything, there are no specific constraints here for data structure selection. Here, code provided an example with a `map` data structure with mixups of `string`. Regarding shell command, the `os/exec` package provides functionality that you are needing here (`exec.Command`). Run your code in [**Playground:**](https://go.dev/play/p/lDMF96HhAQX)

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

type UserGroups map[string][]string

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("/etc/passwd")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    userGroups := make(UserGroups)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        fields := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ":")

        username := fields[0]

        cmd := exec.Command("id", "-Gn", username)
        output, err := cmd.Output()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        groups := strings.Split(strings.TrimSpace(string(output)), " ")

        userGroups[username] = groups
    }

    for username, groups := range userGroups {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", username, strings.Join(groups, ", "))
    }
}
```

Playground output:

```
operator: operator
mail: mail
www-data: www-data
bin: bin
sys: sys
sync: users
nobody: nobody
root: root, wheel
daemon: daemon

Program exited.
```

Comment: Will this work when I ssh into the server? I think I tried the exec.command() too. But they all give session errors. I want to perform the above task with minimum number of sessions.